# Image display's on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, html, image

I have exactly same code on my localhost,and it display's everything perfectly,so i copied file to server that im hosting on (000webhost.com) and now it didnt display image,when i open inspect element,it show's that image is there,and image is also uploaded to save folder with that file.Image is at the bottom of the file.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<!--
body{
background-color:black;
}

 #form{
position:absolute;
top:180px;
left:37%;
border-radius:20px;
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:50px;
background-color:white;
z-index:1;
}

#login_b{
position:relative;
left:38px;
top:30px;
width:150px;
color:white;
background-color:#777777;
 }

#header1 {
position:absolute;
top:115px;
left:39%;
text-shadow:10px 5px 5px #888888;
color:white;
z-index:2;
}

#header2 {
position:absolute;
left:20%;
top:-50px;
font-size:100px;
color: yellow;
}

#image1 {
height:77%;
position:relative;
top:280px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
</body>

<?php
include 'scripts/config.php';
checkIfLoggedIn();
//error_reporting(0);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$q = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password =     '$password'");
$query = $q->execute(array(
$username,
$password
));

$count = $q->fetchColumn();
if($count){
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
    header('Location: main.php');
    return;
} else {
    echo '<font color="white">You have entered and incorrect login!</font>';
}
}

?>

<h1 id="header2">ARAM STATS!</h1>
<h1 id="header1">Admin login</h1>
<div id="form">
<form action="" method="POST">

Username:
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>

Password:
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" id="login_b">
</form>
</div>
<img src="/lolimage.jpg" id="image1">
</body>
</html>
```

Do i have to change something on the server? When i highlight it,it becomes blue: http://piclair.com/album   but it doenst display it.Doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Where is located the image file ? If it's in the same directory of your page you should try

```
<img src="lolimage.jpg" id="image1">
```

You mention a "save folder", is it where are located your images ? If so you should add the directory to the path.

```
<img src="save/lolimage.jpg" id="image1">
```

Comment: The file that i showed,is index.php it is located in the same folder image.jpg is located.

Comment: So it's not comming from your path but from the server. Otherwise it would work with src="lolimage.jpg". Are you sure of the extension ? Is the file huge ? Try without your CSS and also try to open it from your browser : http://yourdomain/lolimage.jpg

Comment: File is 250kb nad im sure of the extension.Removing CSS didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your sites base url before your image name.
This may help you

for example,

```
<img src="<your_sites_base_url>/<image_name>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be lot of reasons -

try to open the image directly by giving folder path in browser like : xyz.com/yourfolder/imagefolder/images.jpg . if you are able to see it then check the src you have given for image. It should be relative path. use src = "../path/image.jpg" based on location of you html/php file and image. If image is in same folder of the file that no need to add '/'

Comment: Ok,i tried "mywebsitename"/lolimage.jpg and it didnt open.It was just white screen.

Comment: what are the locations of image and html file relative to htdocs folder?

Comment: When i go to file manager,there's 2 files: DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE and .ftpquota and 1 folder: public_html where i hold all my website,so image and html file is in public_html folder.Inside that folder i have another folder,for other images,where is htaccess file.

Comment: i didn't find any reference of image "lolimage.jpg" in this url piclair.com/album :(